# GLMER, GHAQ and marginaled coefficients

Tags: mixed-model, confidence-interval, interpretation, glmmadaptive

I am confused about the GLMM procedures and their reporting. I have tried to follow @Ben Bolker on [mixed effect model](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#can-i-use-aic-for-mixed-models-how-do-i-count-the-number-of-degrees-of-freedom-for-a-random-effect). However, I am confused after the GLMAdaptive [approach](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/articles/Methods_MixMod.html#marginalized-coefficients). I will lay out my problem.

The experiment involved breeding organisms in three "Treatment" (Gregarious, Intermediate and Sparse). The response variable is "morphs" (red/ blue). However, the treatment was carried in similar sized boxes. During the breeding, organisms died at different time-points (even though they were staged before the experiment began). I have included "Box" as a random effect (random intercept). I have two other numeric predictors.

```
require(lme4)
e1<- glmer(morph ~ Treatment + growth + weight + (1| Box), data = e, family = "binomial", control = glmerCont`enter code here`rol(optimizer = "bobyqa"), nAGQ = 25, na.action = "na.fail")
```

I use GHAquadarature with 25 points. Random intercept model. The aim is to study population parameters and not random effects.

Checked for overdispersion.

```
overdisp_fun(e1)
      chisq       ratio         rdf           p 
245.2838191   0.7836544 313.0000000   0.9981553
```

I then standardized the global model with the "arms" package (this will centre and scale the numeric variables).

```
require(arm)
e2<-standardize(e1)

summary(e2)

      
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Adaptive Gauss-Hermite Quadrature, nAGQ = 25) ['glmerMod']
     Family: binomial  ( logit )
    Formula: morph ~ Treatment + z.growth + z.weight + (1 | Box)
       Data: e
    Control: glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa")
    
         AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
       270.7    293.3   -129.3    258.7      313 
    
    Scaled residuals: 
        Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
    -2.1963 -0.4681 -0.2527 -0.1364  4.1039 
    
    Random effects:
     Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
     Box    (Intercept) 0.9245   0.9615  
    Number of obs: 319, groups:  Box, 46
    
    Fixed effects:
                          Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
    (Intercept)            -1.1288     0.3521  -3.206  0.00134 **
    Treatmentintermediate  -1.5315     0.5933  -2.581  0.00985 **
    Treatmentsparse        -1.9510     0.7181  -2.717  0.00659 **
    z.growth               -1.1441     0.4570  -2.503  0.01230 * 
    z.weight                0.3748     0.3784   0.991  0.32191   
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
    
    Correlation of Fixed Effects:
                (Intr) Trtmntn Trtmnts z.grwt
    Trtmntntrmd -0.512                       
    Tretmntsprs -0.478  0.311                
    z.growth     0.272  0.058  -0.172        
    z.weight     0.062 -0.123  -0.091   0.139 

           
display(e2)
            coef.est coef.se
        (Intercept)           -1.13     0.35  
        Treatmentintermediate -1.53     0.59  
        Treatmentsparse       -1.95     0.72  
        z.growth              -1.14     0.46  
        z.weight               0.37     0.38  
        
        Error terms:
         Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
         Box      (Intercept) 0.96    
         Residual             1.00    
        ---
        number of obs: 319, groups: Box, 46
        AIC = 270.7, DIC = 186.8
        deviance = 222.7
```

After this, I derive a series of candidate models from the e2 global model. I compare them with AICc. I set the threshold of 2 AICc units for the most competitive models while the best model is with the least AICc.

**Interpreting random effect: Does the std. deviation of 0.96 indicates any mild/ strong variation among the boxes? Or there is no effect of "boxes" on the response variable? Should I talk anything about the random effect in the results/ discussion?**

**Marginal AIC: Does the AICc in the summary correspond to marginal AIC? Since I am not interested in random effects, I have not used the (conditional AIC)cAIC.**

**Should we report estimates and CI of the best model (least AICc) or the global model?**

I then compute the confidence intervals of the global model.

```
2.5 %     97.5 %
    sd_(Intercept)|Box     0.5000825  1.6123814
    (Intercept)           -1.8995190 -0.4334229
    Treatmentintermediate -2.8496460 -0.4161077
    Treatmentsparse       -3.5398772 -0.6348531
    z.growth              -2.1021283 -0.2879385
    z.weight              -0.3676294  1.1247416
```

**Can I report the estimates from the summary table and the CI'S?**
Here the CI's indicate that weight does not relatively influence morphs compared to other predictors.

**Do we need to report the *marginalised coefficients*, as I [read](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/articles/Methods_MixMod.html#marginalized-coefficients) that GLMM gives estimates conditional on the random effects?**. Can we get marginalised coefficients for the glmer() too?
Hence I used another package GLMMAdative for that.

When I used the GLMMAdaptive, I had to manually centre and scale the numeric variables.

```
require(GLMMadaptive)
p1<-scale(e$growth, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)
p2<-scale(e$weight, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)

p3<- mixed_model(fixed = morph ~ Treatment + p1 + p2, random = ~1| Box, data = e, family = "binomial", na.action = "na.fail")

Call:
mixed_model(fixed = morph ~ Treatment + e$growth + e$weight, 
    random = ~1 | Box, data = e, family = "binomial", na.action = "na.fail")

Data Descriptives:
Number of Observations: 319
Number of Groups: 46 

Model:
 family: binomial
 link: logit 

Fit statistics:
   log.Lik     AIC      BIC
 -133.7745 279.549 290.5209

Random effects covariance matrix:
               StdDev
(Intercept) 0.9834821

Fixed effects:
                      Estimate Std.Err z-value    p-value
(Intercept)             0.0093  3.2641  0.0029 0.99771599
Treatmentintermediate  -1.5078  0.6005 -2.5108 0.01204580
Treatmentsparse        -2.4181  0.7187 -3.3647 0.00076634
e$growth               -0.2491  0.4727 -0.5270 0.59816003
e$weight                0.5773  4.3958  0.1313 0.89551131

Integration:
method: adaptive Gauss-Hermite quadrature rule
quadrature points: 11


Optimization:
method: EM
converged: TRUE
```

Calculating the CI for log odds ratio:

```
exp(confint(p3))
                           2.5 %   Estimate    97.5 %
(Intercept)           0.19982585 0.39358842 0.7752342
Treatmentintermediate 0.06823391 0.22139601 0.7183553
Treatmentsparse       0.02178281 0.08909298 0.3643956
p1                    0.63238218 0.90745182 1.3021695
p2                    0.74471295 1.02139536 1.4008733
```

So what do we infer from the CI (obtained by this method, compared to earlier CI), here that all parameters are likely influential for the dependent variable? (since no term includes zero?) Or am I missing something major here? In the sense of interpreting CI's?

Can we report the estimates and CI based on glmer() function or are they/are they not conditional on the random effects? How do I explain the random effect in my case?

Comment: You can report whatever is relevant for you. `glmer` estimates are conditional on the random effects and does not have the option to output marginal estimates, as far as I know.

Comment: I got an inkling of how to understand the random error from this question already asked https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130313/how-do-i-interpret-the-variance-of-random-effect-in-a-generalized-linear-mixed-m. Also I would be reporting the estimates conditional on the random effect and the CI's computed therein (profile). Thanks @RobertLong!